# Laravel 8 queue batch callback funktions crash on calling $this Object

Tags: laravel, callback, queue, batch-processing

I want to do some specific tasks in the callback functions like logging via `print_r()` method or calling object methods via `$this` object. But all that fails so i wonder what the scope of these callback functions is. Its somewhat mysterious. I didnt find anything regarding this via google, i think this feature is too new and hasnt been explored widely.

What works though is calling static class methods like

```
self::doSomething();
```

Here is the basic structure from the official doc, added my methods in `then` and `finally` callback branches:

```
$batch = Bus::batch(
    $batchedObjects
)->then(function (Batch $batch) {
    // All jobs completed successfully...
    // this method call does not work
    $this->doSomething();
})->catch(function (Batch $batch, Throwable $e) {
    // First batch job failure detected...
})->finally(function (Batch $batch) {
    // The batch has finished executing...
    // this method call works
    self::doSomething();
})->onQueue('myQueue')->dispatch();
```

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm running into something similar it appears.

Comment: Found the following: 1) https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/problem-with-batch-callbacks 2) https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/problem-with-batch-callbacks

Comment: I found that too. The issue still exists, regardless of that workaround.